# focus submit button and select right tab in chrome doesn't work

Tags: javascript, tabs, focus

it only selects right tab but it does not focus submit button:

```
function(tab) {
  var winid = tab.windowId;
    var tabid = tab.id;

        chrome.tabs.getAllInWindow(winid, function(tabs) {
      for (var j = 0; j < tabs.length;++j) {
        if (tabs[j].id == tabid) {
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { code: "document.getElementById('submit').focus()" });
             chrome.tabs.update(tabs[(j + 1) % tabs.length].id, {
            'selected': true
          });
          break;
        }
      }
    });
```

Comment: I found it. i need some code change like this:
 chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { code: 'document.getElementById(\"submit\").focus()' });
It worked

Comment: I still wrong , it works on some website but not at all.